# Do any USB cables support PD at low current only?

Tags: usb, usb-pd

We have an application that requires around 7.5W of power delivery over USB.  However, we would like the cable to be as thin and as light as possible.  So, best case scenario, we would use USB-PD to negotiate at low current 5V and then switch to 20V (also low current). Unfortunately, this feels like a dangerous USB cable to build since someone could use it for another PD application and easily melt the wire.  I imagine this would be somewhat possible if we included circuitry in the cable itself but is there any precedent for doing that or better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A "PD-aware" cable with A or B ends (or any USB-C cable) isn't conforming unless it supports at least 3A (5A is optional and requires fancier active cables).

And USB-PD is written with this in mind. If a power source supports 20V it must also support 5, 9, and 15V (all at 3A), and indeed if it supports 20V it must support 20V at 2.25A or more — because 15V 3A is 45W, so it's not allowed to support *less* than 45W in 20V mode, for reasons of avoiding labeling confusion. The idea that any PD cable can do 3A is very much baked in; there's no provision for a source to detect a non-marked cable and say "I can do any voltage, but only at 1.5A". If the current is limited to 1.5A then the voltage is also limited to 5V.

Of course *electrically* your idea is alright, but it won't pass logo testing and it may expose you to liability if anyone burns down their house while using your equipment. Any clever solutions you come up with won't fix the first issue and I wouldn't count on them to fix the second.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on USB regulation, so I will take @hobbs's answer for granted.

What might be a solution, would be, instead of using a complete USB cable, to have one end of the cable entering your device without any connector (or with a custom, non USB, connector).

This way, you still have the USB plug on the power supply side, but your cable is no longer general purpose, so no risk of someone trying to use it for higher power than designed for.

But still, I strongly advise to check beforehand that this will not pose any problems for regulation/certification. And of course, having a non detachable cable is not always handy, and if damaged, there is no easy way to replace it.